# Python Regex Issue Involving "TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object"

Tags: regex, python-3.x, typeerror

I am having an issue involving the type error in the title with the following code:

```
def testregex():
    import re

inputfilename = input("Enter Input File Name: ")
keyword = input("Enter Keyword: ")
outputfilename = input("Enter Output File Name: ")

pattern = re.escape(keyword) + r"[\s\n]+([\w\.]+)\s+(\w+)\s+(\w+)[\s\n]+(\d+\s\w+\s\w+)[\s\n]+(\w+\s?\w+,\s\w+\s\d+)"

inputfile = open(inputfilename, "r")
outputfile = open(outputfilename, "w")

match = re.findall(pattern, inputfile)
if match:
    for tuple in match:
        outputfile.write(tuple[0]+ " " + tuple[1]+ " " + tuple[2] + "\n" +tuple[3]+ "\n" +tuple[4] + "\n")

inputfile.close()
outputfile.close()
```

Having run this many times with parameters as shown, I still receive the following error regardless:

```
Enter Input File Name: lettersinput.txt

Enter Keyword: Sincerely,

Enter Output File Name: Lettersoutput2.txt
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-32-32667d9b5684>", line 13, in <module>
    match = re.findall(pattern, inputfile)

  File "/Users/Jmsquillaro/anaconda/lib/python3.5/re.py", line 213, in findall
    return _compile(pattern, flags).findall(string)

TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object
```

What am I doing wrong and what can be fixed without over-complicating the code? The script is supposed to locate an input file, perform the listed regex on it and insert the results as tuples into a new output file that is titled by the user. For your reference, when this code is run, the output file is created but is blank. Also, is there anything else I could do to make this run smoother and to avoid any other foreseeable problem? Thank you so much!

Comment: `inputfile` is a file object, you need to read it first. `match = re.findall(pattern, inputfile.read())`.

Comment: @tdelaney That was it! I must have overlooked this as I was looking for something more complex. Thank you!